# Runtime Error During Recursion

Tags: c++, runtimeexception

I am coding a program with the help of recursive calling of a function, I get correct output till my test input gets solved within 10 steps of recursion but if I increase the input value to 11 it starts giving run time error as:
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

the code snippet of the function is:

```
void find(int x) {    
    if(ctr==n-1) {
        po[k]=x;
        k++;
        ctr--;
        return;
    } else {
        ctr++;
        find(x+a);
        ctr++;
        find(x+b);  
        ctr--;
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the size of po? It seems you initial po to be int po[10].

Comment: all pieces are not here. how are `ctr, n, k, a & b` declared and initialized?

Comment: It's 1000 i.e int po[1000]

Comment: n is 11 a is 3 b is 5

Comment: ctr=0 which is initialized as a global variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran it, it needs space in `po` for **1024** items with x=11, 
you only have **1000**

Comment: What to do for large values like 58 or so

Comment: I have declared po[1024] as global variable

Comment: for a large value like 58, you would need 2^57 items, that wont fit in most computers. rethink how you get to the final answer.